# How to hide my IP address when sending emails using Javamail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, ip-address

I made a Java application that sends emails using JavaMail and it works fine.
The problem is, I want to hide my IP(like when you send an email using Gmail on a browser) before sending it to another user on my app.
I tried to use the setFrom() method to change the from field, but it still reveals my IP.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to hide your IP? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm hosting a web server, and I want to avoid spamming and DDoS attack. That's all.

Comment: Ok, now it's clearer that it is for own security purposes and not for start spamming your friends or for a DDoS attack in a revenge on some institution.

Comment: @technophyle If you are hosting a webserver, [a DNS lookup will reveal your IP](http://whois.domaintools.com/gmail.com). You may be able to hide it in your emails, but it won't be that hard to find it.

Comment: @luiggi I'm asking you, 'cause i'm really curious, if what I'm trying to do is SO bad, why do Gmail and Hotmail do that for me? They might do that to protect my privacy, right?

Comment: I don't think is bad. In fact, I didn't think what were your intentions for this. That's why I raised a question in the first comment, mainly because this site won't help on the generation of attacks or logical bombs. Anyway, the case these big companies do it doesn't mean you should unless you have a very specific security matter that should be explained in your question. Also, as noted by BackSlash, that won't protect you that much since the main server IP can still be obtained by DNS lookup. You probably want to raise this question as security more than a plain curiosity.

Comment: And I don't think that's the only thing they do to protect my *privacy* (yeah, let's save all my private important stuff in a black box and let a company handle and secure it for me).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to hide your IP in the mail header. It's not actually undeer your control. The server at the receiving end know which IP it received the message from and add's that IP to the header of the message.

Spammers generally search the net for more or less open relays to exploit those. A good configuration for your SMTP server will do a lot to prevent those.